# spark script fails : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.addDelegationTokens

Tags: ibm-cloud, biginsights

I am trying to run a simple spark script on BigInsights on Cloud:

```
lines = sc.textFile(license_filename, 1)
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
              .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
              .reduceByKey(add) \
              .filter(lambda x: x[0].isalnum())
```

This resulted in the following exception:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o45.partitions.
: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.addDelegationTokens(KMSClientProvider.java:888)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyProviderDelegationTokenExtension.addDelegationTokens(KeyProviderDelegationTokenExtension.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.addDelegationTokens(DistributedFileSystem.java:2233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator.authenticate(DelegationTokenAuthenticator.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.openConnection(AuthenticatedURL.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator.doDelegationTokenOperation(DelegationTokenAuthenticator.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator.getDelegationToken(DelegationTokenAuthenticator.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL.getDelegationToken(DelegationTokenAuthenticatedURL.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider$2.run(KMSClientProvider.java:875)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider$2.run(KMSClientProvider.java:870)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.addDelegationTokens(KMSClientProvider.java:870)
    ... 30 more
```

I have seen similar questions, but none relating to BigInsights (hadoop) on Bluemix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support team checked and the KMS was not running.  You can verify this for yourself with

```
netstat -anp | grep 16000
```

Output should be like

```
tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:16000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 34632/java
```

If you do not see output similar to above, contact bluemix support.  They will probably need to run the following command on your cluster:

```
sudo -u kms /home/kms/server/hadoop/sbin/kms.sh start
```

Comment: I wasn't able to run the sudo command b/c I didnt have access privileges, but when I contacted support, indeed it was the kms that wasnt running.